# Is there any way to temporarily disable CCCheck in vs2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-contracts

I have a vs solution with 20 or so projects, when I compile it runs CCCheck in the background and slows down my compilation (unless I go to processes and repeatedly kill CCCheck.exe). In vs2013 project properties I could not find a way to disable it. I am also using Resharper which, I believe, should not be an issue.

In project > Properties > Code Analysis I already disabled "Enable Code Analysis on Build"

Comment: The option "Enable Code Analysis on Build" should work. Are you sure you set the option for the right (all?) projects and the right configurations?

Comment: Yes double checked for all the projects

Comment: I am using code contracts from system.diagnostics.contracts within my code, does it have anything to do with this?